# trying to add ckeditor to my angular application - getting CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

Here are the steps that I took:

1)First I added the ng-ckeditor.min.js into my project

2)I included it into the page like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ng-ckeditor.min.js"></script>`

3) I added the dependancy into the module like this:

```
var summariesApp = angular.module('summariesApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCkeditor']);
```

I am getting an error in my console: "CKEDITOR is not defined". The error is in ng-ckeditor.min.js itself.

Here is the Github:

https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you include the script before or after you included angular?

Comment: Have you made sure that your ckeditor script is after angular script?

Comment: yes it is after the angular script

Comment: Did you include CKEditor itself (not ng-ckeditor)?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: figured it out. Thanks dfsq.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually add a reference to the actual ckeditor.js file in your html file.

open the index.html and look for the section which is managed by bower - it is marked with an opening and a closing comment.

add these lines above this section,

> ```
> <!-- manually added js files -->
> <script src="bower_components/ng-ckeditor/libs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
> ```

note the relative path which might not be exactly as on my machine.